# A valid solution to write objects containing strings into files?

Tags: string, c++11, file-io, new-operator

Please can someone explain the meaning of the 2nd line of the following code?

```
Book *B;
B=(Book *)new char[sizeof(Book)];
f1.read((char*)B,sizeof(Book));
```

This was one of the suggestions I found for writing an object of class Book (which contains `std::strings`) into a file.
PS: It works !!

Comment: This only seems to work. I bet the implementation of `std::string` happens to use small-string optimization, and you happen to only place short enough strings into your `string` variables. Give your `Book` a long title (say, longer than 32 characters), and see how well it works then. Formally, this program exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Igor - you're right it didn't work with longer strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you included does not "write objects." It reads an array of bytes from `f1`.

That code is not correct C++ either. You can *never* do byte copies of a C++ object that contains other objects, because they might contain pointers or virtual function tables. Copying them from a file is even worse because the pointers will point to memory that doesn't even exist anymore. And FYI, `std::string` definitely has a pointer.

Comment: Could you please suggest a way of writing/reading objects with strings? I have to do this without using any external libraries (eg, boost) and I have tried overloading operators >> and << and writing and reading individual elements of the object from the file. Its working ...but not convinced its the best answer

Comment: Reading and writing objects is called *serializing*. The basic way to do this in C++ is indeed the `operator<<` and `operator>>` functions.